# This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK, Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

please help my solve this error i get when i try to archive my app.

> This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK, Xcode

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Xcode app to app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545563/xcode-app-to-app-store) by the same author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using iOS 4.1 as the Base SDK for your *Distribution* configuration. Select **Latest (iOS 5.0)** instead.

Apple does currently only accept 5.0 and also 4.3 for current submissions. This could change any day to 5.0 only.

Also your *Distribution* configuration seems to be a little messed up as it accepts **i386 (32 and 64 bit)** architectures. I would strongly suggest you to remove it entirely and replace it with a fresh copy of your Release configuration.

As a last step, make sure the Archiving scheme actually uses your distribution configuration. (edit scheme, select archiving, select Distribution configuration)